# Calculate change of pressure in a football due to insertion of a solid ball

Tags: pressure

Let's say I have a football of radius r1 inflated to pressure p1 and insert a solid metal ball of radius r2 (without losing any air), to give a new pressure of p2.

Is there a formula I can use that gives me p2 in terms of r1, r2 and p1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is carried out without any change in temperature(isothermally)(which is a very good approximation), you can use

$P_1V_1=P_2V_2$

Use $V_1$ as initial volume of balloon(spherical) and $V_2$ as the final volume of air remaining.